# Raspberry Pi as a gateway between BLE beacon and IBM Watson

Tags: bluetooth, node-red, gateway, watson

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi 3 as a gateway to send data from a BLE beacon to IBM Watson platform. I can view the data from the beacon in the Raspberry Pi console but I don't understand how can I send the data to Watson.

I've tried using Node-RED and the Generic-BLE node but it seems this node only works with dongles and i'm using the embedded Bluetooth of the RaspberryPi to read the data from the BLE beacon.

Has anyone tried to do this and was successful?

Answer (score 0):

There should be absolutely no difference between a USB BLE dongle and the built in BLE on a RPi3.

You will have to either run Node-RED as root or use the following command to allow NodeJS to access the BLE adapter.

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip $(eval readlink -f `which node`)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but the 'which node' part should be replaced by what exactly?

Comment: Nothing, `which node` is a command that will return the path of the installed version of node

Comment: So, i literally copy and paste the command and execute it, right?

Comment: Hello @hardillb... i wasn't able to read the Minor value from the beacons but now i'm able to ackowledge them in the Node-RED UI. My flow already has 3 nodes for 3 beacons i'm using and i wanted to debug the values read to the debug tab but i'm missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [node-red-contrib-bleacon](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-bleacon) instead of Generic-BLE, as Generic-BLE is designed for connectable GATT Bluetooth LE modules.  BLE Beacons are typically transmit only devices that often don't have public interfaces to connect over GATT.

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Comment: Hello @davidgyoung, i've install the node you suggested but when i start Node-RED UI, shouldn't a new node "scanBLE" be there to be used?